# Four letter word with at least a "j", elegant and most compatible regex solution?

Tags: regex

I have this problem which made my scratch my head:

Is there a way to use regular expression to test a 4 characters string with at least a letter "J"? This is what I come with:

```
^(j...|.j..|..j.|...j)$
```

Yes, I admit it's ugly, and it's would be mad if the question changes 4 character to 10 character, or change "at least one j" to "with at least one j AND one k"

What the more elegant and compatible way to write an RegEx for this?

Additional question:

1. If there is no easy answer, academically, what's the limit of RegExp? Why it can't solve simple problem like this?
2. Any DSL suitable for these kinds of tasks?
3. What's the best RegEx for "10 character string with at least one j and one k" ?

Comment: I think it's pretty okay actually, I mean, were dealing with regexps..

Comment: As for your 2nd question: Yes, regular expressions are pretty well understood, in terms of expressive power, a regular expression is equal to a regular language, which can be processed by a finite acceptor, i.e. a deterministic finite automata - but most regular expression engines implement languages of higher expressive power. Read any introductionary text on theoretical computer science to get an overview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your regex engine supports lookahead (most do), you can use

```
^(?=.*j).{4}$
```

The lookahead `(?=.*j)` asserts that there is a `j` somewhere in the string without actually consuming any of the string for the match. The following `.{4}` will then match a four-character string.

The `^` and `$` anchors make sure that the string is matched in its entirety.

If you want to add more constraints, simply add another lookahead:

```
^(?=.*j)(?=.*k).{10}$
```

matches if at least one `j` and one `k`are present in a string that's exactly 10 characters long. Etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can use positive look ahead as:

```
^(?=.*j)[a-zA-Z]{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can make sure the test string length is exactly 4 characters, you could do it with `^([A-Za-z])*j([A-Za-z])*$`  . That is, 0 or more letters followed by j, followed by zero or more letters which will guarantee the string has at least one 'j' either at the beginning, middle or the end.

Edit: actually you'd be better just doing the lookahead as in the other answers!

Comment: Thanks! I thought about it, too. Like I said, what if I want to test a 10 characters string contains at least one j AND one k ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try answering Additional Question #1.

This is indeed a simple task, but that does not mean it's simple with *every* tool you can use. And regular expressions are just a tool, and in my opinion the wrong one in this case.

If you just want to test a string with the constraints that it has to be 4 chars long and contain a `j`, then every language provides better ways to do this. Those constraints are not a pattern, or expression: they are just a length and a literal substring. Regular expressions are useful when you have to describe a pattern which is not easily splittable in trivial fixed terms.